# Cordova 2.8.1: camera.getPicture with photolibarary source on ios

Tags: ios, cordova

Using cordova 2.8.1 I am trying to do a camera.getPicture with photolibrary.  It seems to be working for android but not for iOS.  below is how I call the getPicture code.  On an iPhone 4s with iOS 6 it allows me to select an image, but as soon as thats done the error callback is called with the argument being null

```
var options = {
          quality : 30,
          destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
          correctOrientation: true,
          targetWidth: 800,
          targetHeight: 800
    };

navigator.camera.getPicture(this.captureSuccessPre, this.captureError, options);
```

I was told to add a timeout around the console.logs.  On phonegaps documentation it states to do so around alerts.  Below is my error callback. which logs [error null]

```
captureError: function(error){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("error " + error); //logs error null
    }, 100);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas.  I have been struggling for a few days.  If it helps any this code works perfect with

```
sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem; seems to be related to the DestinationType.FILE_URI.

Try this:

```
var options = {
      quality : 30,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      correctOrientation: true,
      targetWidth: 800,
      targetHeight: 800
};
```

Comment: You are awesome! thank you so much. I would give an upvote, but I guess I am too much of a stackoverflow beginner to be allowed to.

Comment: One thing I did notice is that this causes the camera capture  (sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA) to not work on an iPad2.

Comment: Yeah, i ran into that too... I switched back to FILE_URI and put in the encodingType: encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG

Seems to work too now...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there was a bug in 2.8.0 - if you upgrade to 2.9.0 it fixes it ([CB-3757] camera.getPicture from photolib fails on iOS - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/2.9.0/changelog)

Comment: Just upgraded and it seems the problem persists in 2.9 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will helping for you

```
function uploadFromGallery(){
      navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,function(message){
            console.log('get picture failed'); },
       {quality: 75,
          destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
          allowEdit:true, 
          targetWidth: 100,
          targetHeight: 100 
      }); 
}
```